# Show and hide panel using radio buttons

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, show-hide, panels

I have two `radio buttons` and two `panels` on my webpage and I would like to `show` panel 1 when radio button1 checked changed and hide panel2 and similarly panel2 needs to be shown when radio button2 checked changed and hide panel1.

This is how I have done with no success

Here are my radio buttons:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" Text="Text" ForeColor="White" GroupName="selection" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton1_CheckedChanged"/>

<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" Text="Image" ForeColor="White" GroupName="selection" OnCheckedChanged="RadioButton2_CheckedChanged"/>
```

This is RadioButton1_CheckedChanged:

```
If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            RadioButton2.Checked = False
            Panel1.Visible = True
            Panel2.Visible = False
 End If
```

This is RadioButton2_CheckedChanged:

```
 If RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            RadioButton1.Checked = False
            Panel1.Visible = False
            Panel2.Visible = True
 End If
```

Comment: Autopostback needs to be set to true for this to effectively work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `autopostback` to true for the radio buttons.
`AutoPostback="True"` include that in your radiobutton tag and you should be good to go.  A simple debug of your code would show you that both events are not called with your current code.

Comment: @John-Thanks for replying and Can I use update panel with a panel and set the radio button postback property to true as I don't want to postback.

Comment: @DotNetter - If you don't want a postback why don't you handle this at the client side not the server side?  Use simple javascript to `getElementById` or `getElementByName` and set the visibility property.  Besides, doing this in server side code has no special / specific purpose based on your existing code ( you aren't processing any data or doing any data intensive work ).